# Cannot load the editActivity page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am creating an application in Android studio that keeps track of the tv-shows that I've watched. However when I try to launch the EditShowActivity, by clicking on an item in my listview my phone app crashes. I can't figure out why or how.

Call to my EditShowActivity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditShowActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_ID, showArrayAdapter.getItem(position).getId());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);            }
        });
```

This is my EditShowActivity

```
public class EditShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Show show;
    private DataSource datasource;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        datasource = new DataSource(this);
        long showId = getIntent().getLongExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_ID, -1);
        show = datasource.getShow(showId);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details_textview);
        textView.setText(show.getShow());

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.details_updateText);

        Button updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.details_updateButton);

        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                show.setShows(editText.getText().toString());
                datasource.updateShow(show);
                Toast.makeText(EditShowActivity.this, "Assignment Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

My activity_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.kevin.androidapp.EditShowActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_edit" />



</FrameLayout>
```

My content_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_edit">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/details_updateText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/details_updateButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:onClick="addListItem"
            android:text="Update" />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have log of exception to post?

Comment: I fear not, I am running it on my phone. No logs

Comment: You have SDK installed right? Just plug phone into workstation and connect to it with ADB (requires "USB debugging" enabled under Settings->Developer options) and run android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat. It's well worth the effort to setup, that logger shows a ton of good info.

Comment: You could try commenting out everything after **`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`** in **`EditShowActivity`**'s **`onCreate()`**. Once that is confirmed working, uncomment **`setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);`** and proceed from there.

Comment: @SamusArin Tried it just crashes straight away

Comment: i'm afraid youre going to need to run this from the IDE with the device plugged in via USB, watch android monitor and when the app crashes you'll see the stack trace in red text, copy paste that here for more help

Comment: well... i feel dumb, I forgot to declare it in the androidmanifest. that's what happens when you pick up old projects

Comment: You would've seen an error in the log indicating this (they're hard to miss being bright red, multi-lined stack trace), saving you a bit of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_ID, (long) showArrayAdapter.getItem(position).getId());
```

then:

```
long showId = (long) getIntent().getLongExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_ID, -1);
```